# Mac OS X Word 2016 (version 15.24...) Changing Comments' Font Size

Tags: ms-office, font, text-editor, formatting

The problem is how to make the **font size** of the **MS Word 2016 Comments** bigger. There seem to be three obvious paths to a simple Comments font size change. However, when each method is attempted the Format data shows one thing but the MS Word Print View Shows nothing has changed visually by size. These methods will change from Arial to Times New Roman etc ... but not the visual size of the font of the Comments.

I can attempt to **change the font size for Comments** if I go to the Home tab and select the style manager. If the cursor is already in a comment the manager will default to the comment style which provides the modify option. As I mentioned earlier, this **will visually change from Arial to Times New Roman or whatnot** but... the font size may be modified from size 10-20+ without any visual change as a result.

The Comments font size info will show to be be retained as changed if do or do not check the save to template box, followed by saving the file, closing Word, and restarting Mac OS X.

When I reopen the file, **the Comments font size does not change**. The type may have been changed from Arial or whatever but not the visual size. When I go to the style manager I note that the number 20 font will be intact as entered but there will still be no visual change in font size as far as Comments show...

I may attempt something easy like CMD+D while the cursor is in a comment area. The font size selected will still show that it has been changed to 20 but the font size visually remains as the default size it was on the first install.

I might also go potentially easier and try going to FORMAT>FONT which is another way to CMD+D but there is still no visual change, however the Word Font window still shows font size as 20.

Please note I chose 20 as a drastic change after I realized I couldn't get any satisfaction visually. What's frustrating is that the MS Word Font Preview window blurb shows visual change but nothing in the actual Word Print View where there are Comments.

I realize I could just save the file into a LibreOffice compatible file type and change the Comments' font size that way... Where is the fun in that? The idealist in me believes that I may be able to perceive a change I selected.

As a last attempt I tried to print to a PDF file and investigate the results in PDF form. Nada on the change of the size ... I did not test this via the View>Draft because I want it to work in the View>Print setting.

Thank you for your input about my dilemma.

Comment: I've been having the exact same issue. Would love to know if anyone found a fix.